# Go-Ethereum compatible with negative difficulty if custom consensus engine is used?

Tags: go-ethereum, clique

Assuming a custom consensus engine similar to Clique proof-of-authority, is block.Difficulty allowed to be negative?

**Why I ask:**

Custom consensus engines can reuse the ReorgNeeded functionality if they use a form of difficulty, and Clique does so. Clique gives inturn validator difficulty 2 and outturn 1. But, since more than one validator can be skipped, this does not scale for skipping more than 1 validator. An alternative is to consider how many were skipped at a certain block. This is easy if difficulty can be negative. Then it can be set to `1-skipped`.

Of course with that, reorg would be rejected until a number of in-turn validators signed on,

```
if diff := externTd.Cmp(localTD); diff > 0 {
    return true, nil
} else if diff < 0 {
    return false, nil
}
```

but that seems like a good thing. With one validator skipped, need at least two in-turn validators (to get to higher difficulty than the chain from the skipped validator). With two skipped, need three in-turn. Etc.